# Mapping an additional column to a composite-id while keeping the property-mapping for it

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, composite-key, join

im using an intermediate entity-class to map additional columns to a jointable and it works fine as long as the Id will be generated from the both fkeys from the involved tables.

I want to implement a 3rd column "revision" from the same entity-class into the composite-id, and still need to use it with normal property-mapping. The composite-id mapping works fine, but the normal mapping for "revision" isnt.

I havnt found a good solution without using redundant data/columns for this problem, but i wonder why ,using entity-classes for jointables with extracolumns is a common way?

I would be gratefull for informations about how to map this correctly, or for informative links about it,  thank you for help.

" Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table backlogaufgabe refers to an unmapped class: int " will be shown with this mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="app.domain">
 <class mutable="false" name="app.domain.BacklogAufgabe" table="backlogaufgabe">
  <composite-id class="BacklogAufgabe$Id" name="id">
   <key-property access="field" column="id_backlog" name="backlogId"/>
   <key-property access="field" column="id_aufgabe" name="aufgabeId"/>
   <key-property access="field" column="revision" name="revisionId"/>
  </composite-id>
  <property column="datum" name="datum" not-null="true" type="date"/>
  <property column="rang" name="rang" not-null="true" type="int"/>

  <property column="revision" name="revision" not-null="true" type="int"/>

  <property column="aufw_schaetzung" name="aufwSchaetzung" not-null="true" type="int"/>
  <property column="aufw_messung" name="aufwMessung" not-null="true" type="int"/>
  <many-to-one cascade="save-update" column="id_aufgabe" insert="false" lazy="false"
    name="aufgabe" not-null="true" update="false"/>
  <many-to-one cascade="save-update" column="id_backlog" insert="false" lazy="false"
    name="backlog"  not-null="true" update="false"/>
  <many-to-one cascade="save-update" column="revision" insert="false" lazy="false"
    name="revision" not-null="true" update="false"/>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

SQL:

```
 CREATE TABLE backlogaufgabe
 (
   id serial NOT NULL,
   id_backlog integer NOT NULL,
   id_aufgabe integer NOT NULL,
   revision integer NOT NULL,
   datum date NOT NULL,
   rang integer NOT NULL,
   aufw_schaetzung integer,
   aufw_messung integer,
   CONSTRAINT backlogaufgabe_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
   CONSTRAINT backlogaufgabe_id_aufgabe_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id_aufgabe)
       REFERENCES aufgabe (id) MATCH SIMPLE
       ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
   CONSTRAINT backlogaufgabe_id_backlog_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id_backlog)
       REFERENCES backlog (id) MATCH SIMPLE
       ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
 )
 WITH (
   OIDS=FALSE
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to put revision as a primary key while creating your table. Because as I've notice on the mapping file you didn't mentioned the `ID` that was already a primary key, and instead you added revision as a primary key which is not the case on the real table. If you see what I mean. So maybe you should put revision as primary key instead of the id.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE backlogaufgabe
(
   id_backlog integer NOT NULL,
   id_aufgabe integer NOT NULL,
   revision integer NOT NULL,
   datum date NOT NULL,
   rang integer NOT NULL,
   aufw_schaetzung integer,
   aufw_messung integer,
   CONSTRAINT backlogaufgabe_pkey PRIMARY KEY (revision),
   CONSTRAINT backlogaufgabe_id_aufgabe_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id_aufgabe)
       REFERENCES aufgabe (id) MATCH SIMPLE
       ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
   CONSTRAINT backlogaufgabe_id_backlog_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id_backlog)
       REFERENCES backlog (id) MATCH SIMPLE
       ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
WITH (
   OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Comment: Hello cascadox, thx for the answer. The revision is and must be redundant, so it cant be the pKey for the table.